# Ionic 3 Wordpress API unsubscribe

Tags: ionic3

```
unsubscribe(siteid) {
    this.user.site_id = siteid;
    console.log('Unsubscribe function');
    console.log(this.user);
    this.wordpressService.unsubscribeSite(this.user).**unsubscribe**((result) => {
        console.log(result);

}, (error) => {
  let errorMessage = error.json();
  if (errorMessage && errorMessage.message) {
    let message = errorMessage.message.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
    let toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 6000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });
    toast.present();
  }
});
```

this code brings the following error
Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unsubscribeSite method in your WordPressService probably returns a variable of type "Observable". That means it's not being subscribed yet. Instead you need a variable of type "Subscription". So, subscribe to the observable and return that result.